# FullCalendar - Get Background event on dayClick

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm currently trying to get an event (type of `background`) when the DayClick is trigger. 
I can't use the EventClick trigger because of the background type (I don't know why but nothing happen in my case, something wrong from FullCalendar ?).

This is my code for the init :

```
$('#calendarRoomUnavailable').fullCalendar({
        height: 'auto',
        header: {
            left : '',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },
        defaultView: 'year',
        defaultDate: getDateFilterRoomAvailable(),
        lang: 'fr',
        firstDay: 1,
        columnFormat: 'ddd D/M',
        selectable : false,
        weekends: false,
        navLinks : false,
        events: basePath + '/agenda/datalist/room_available',
        viewRender: function (view, element) {

        },
        eventRender: function(event,element){
            if(event.rendering === "background"){
                element.data(event); //store the event data inside the element
            }
        },
        dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            console.log(jsEvent)
        },
        editable:false,
    });
```

[Quick look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dD8w.png)

What I want:

When I click on a day, I want the get the event(background) related to the day (I've got only one event per day in my calendar).

Currently I'm working with the eventRender + dayClick :

```
 eventRender: function(event,element){
            if(event.rendering === "background"){
                element.data(event); //store the event data inside the element
            }
        },
 dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            console.log(jsEvent)
[...] 
}
```

With the console.log JSEvent on the DayClick, I know it get me the wrong `<td>` :
[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPCUp.jpg)

Because, when I try to get the target `<td>` with the class `fc-bgevent`, nothing happens :

```
dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            console.log(jsEvent)
            if (jsEvent.target.classList.contains('fc-bgevent')) {
                console.log($(jsEvent.target).data());
            }
```

If I try to go to the HTML element `target` getted by the `jsEvent`, it shows me the wrong `<td>` and I can't do anything with that ...

[HTML Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRdeS.png)

Does someone know how to bypass that ?

Thanks !

*Code to get one event from a date :*

```
function getEventFromDate(date) {
        var allEvents = [];
        allEvents = $('#calendarRoomUnavailable').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
        var event = $.grep(allEvents, function (v) {
            return +v.start === +date;
        });
        if (event.length > 0) {
            return event[0];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: _" can't use the EventClick trigger because of the background type (I don't know why..."_ https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick says "eventClick will not be triggered for background events."

Comment: The problem with your alternative approach is the the `eventRender` stores the data in the _event_ element, not the _day_ element. So you can't match them up. Since you know there'll only be one element per day, simply use the https://fullcalendar.io/docs/clientEvents method to retrieve events whose start date matches the `date` parameter in the dayClick callback. You'll only get one, and it'll be your background event.

Comment: @ADyson hi again, I meant by that, I don't know why the function to get an event background is not implemented while the method to get an event is done.

Comment: I don't know either. You'd have to ask the maintainers of fullCalendar why they wrote it like that. I would guess that they intended that background events were just to highlight areas on the calendar and that people would not want to use them for anything more active than that, but maybe their assumption was wrong!

Comment: @ADyson currently it work like that, but at each click I call a function to get all events and if the date match, I'll return it. But it takes one seconde to make it, and I want to optimise that. POST update for the code

Comment: @ADyson It's pretty old right now but the request to get something like that is already done, and no response .. [Github Request](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2808)

Comment: Instead of just calling `$('#calendarRoomUnavailable').fullCalendar('clientEvents');` and then filtering manually on all the events, use the `filter` parameter described in the documentation to run a callback which will directly filter each event e.g. `$('#calendarRoomUnavailable').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) { if (event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD") == date.format("YYYY-MM-DD")) { return true; } else { return false; } });`. I think this should work a bit faster.

Comment: Re the feature request...the calendar is developed mostly by one volunteer as far as I know. So they do not have endless time to add new functionality. They do accept code contributions though...so you're always free to write the code for the feature yourself and submit it for inclusion in the finished product.

Answer (score 0):

After the @ADyson comments, my final function look like this :

```
function getEventFromDate(date) {
        var eventToReturn = null;

        $('#calendarRoomUnavailable').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
            var event_start = formatDateYmd(new Date(date),'-');
            var date_formated = formatDateYmd(new Date(event.start),'-');

            if(event_start === date_formated) {
                eventToReturn = event;
            }
        });

        return eventToReturn;
    }
```

with a small function to get a formated date without library *like Moment.js or Date.js*:

```
function formatDateYmd(value,$delimiter)
    {
        var year = value.getFullYear();
        var month = (value.getMonth()+1) < 10 ? '0'+(value.getMonth()+1) : (value.getMonth()+1);
        var day = value.getDate() < 10 ? '0'+value.getDate() : value.getDate();
        return year  + $delimiter +
            month + $delimiter +
            day;
    }
```

I hope to find something more performant, but this one divide the execution time by two.

[Keep an eye on it](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2808)

Thanks again.